# Resolving each object of a hasMany relation before getting object properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model named Order which has a hasMany relation to items. When I do the following

```
Order.get('items').then(function(items){
    items.forEach(function(item, index){
       console.log(item.get('name')); // gives undefined

       item.then(); // undefined function then

       item.get('name').then();  // then of undefined

       //Basically unable to do this
       someOtherNewItemObject.set('name', item.get('name')); // someOtherNewItemObject this is an ember object

       // For some reason this doesn't even get updated in the future when promise is resolved
    })

})
```

And then when I do this in the handlebars template

```
{{someOtherNewItemObject.name}} // doesn't display anything or get updated.
```

Basically I am trying to copy the properties of a model to another ember object, which I wished updated in the template when the model resolves itself.

Edit:

The models for orders:

```
orderid: attr('String'),
hotel: belongsTo('hotel'),
user: belongsTo('user'),
items: hasMany('item',{async:true}),
quantities: attr(),
address: belongsTo('deliveryLocation'),
status: attr('Number'),
createDate: attr('date', {defaultValue: new Date()}),
updateDate: attr('Date')
```

The model for Items :

```
name: attr('String'),
menu: belongsTo('menu'), // Menu Id
price: attr('Number'),
cuisine: attr('String'),
available: attr('boolean'),
offer: belongsTo('offer'),
createDate: attr('Date'),
updateDate: attr('Date')
```

Now as u can see the items doesn't contain index or quantities(these are present in the orders model), so I was just trying to create another object like so

```
var tempItem = Ember.Object.create({
  index: null,
  name: null,
  price: null,
  quantity: null,
  subtotal: null
});
```

The data from the server is being returned perfectly and everything works fine (templates auto update) if I just use the items and orders model as is, but if i try to copy them into tempItem and use that instead it doesn't seem to work(no auto updation in templates).

The tempItem is cutally created and used inside a component. I pass the Order model as an arguemnt to the component and then do this.

```
setupItems: function(){
    var self = this;
    var order = this.get('order');
    var tempItems = this.get('modifiedItems'); // modifiedItems is Ember.A() initially
    var quantities = order.get('quantities');
    var tempItem = Ember.Object.create({
                       index: null,
                       name: null,
                       price: null,
                       quantity: null,
                       subtotal: null
                  });
    var count = 0;
    order.get('items').then(function(items){
      items.forEach(function(item, index){
        count++;
        tempItem.set('index', index+1);
        tempItem.set('name', item.get('name'));
        tempItem.set('price', item.get('price'));
        tempItem.set('quantity', quantities[index]);
        tempItem.set('subtotal', parseInt(tempItem.get('price'))*             parseInt(tempItem.get('quantity')));

        tempItems.pushObject(tempItem);
        tempItem = Ember.Object.create({
          index: null,
          name: null,
          price: null,
          quantity: null,
          subtotal: null
        });
      });
    });
},
```

Comment: can you show your models, and json being returned?

Comment: I have added the models just like you asked.

Comment: Can you add and show the context of the some other object and how its set on the controller

Comment: I have added the code for the object(tempItem). It is set in a component rather than a controller.